# Pine script : ta cross with circle

Tags: pine-script

I want to add circle when the 2 lines cross.

Here the code and i add the last line but it's a error.

```
indicator(title="Relative Vigor Index", shorttitle="RVGI", format=format.price, precision=4, 
timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(10, title="Length", minval=1)
rvi = math.sum(ta.swma(close-open), len)/math.sum(ta.swma(high-low),len)
sig = ta.swma(rvi)
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)
plot(rvi, color=#008000, title="RVGI", offset = offset)
plot(sig, color=#FF0000, title="Signal", offset = offset)
plot(ta.cross(rvi, sig), color= #00ff0a, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 2)
```

ta.cross work in a another script.

I don't know.

Thanks for your help.

Have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`series` argument of the `plot()` function expects `series int/float` and you are passing a `bool` (`ta.cross` returns boolean).

You can use the ternary operator to fix that.

Below code will put a circle on the green line of your indicator whenever there is a cross.

```
plot(ta.cross(rvi, sig) ? rvi : na, color= #00ff0a, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 2)
```

[image]

Below code will put a circle on the red line of your indicator whenever there is a cross.

[image]